# Adding changes from the latest commit to the commit from the past

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repo that have the following commits:

```
commit 72d7e34f41b0b53992fb5d36276714d1aac4dc46 (HEAD -> main)
Author: Mateusz Urbański <mateuszurbanski@yahoo.pl>
Date:   Thu Apr 22 12:03:53 2021 +0200

    Add missing test

commit fb8cbd242a2c686f36fc957dd1e866251be36fc5 (origin/main)
Author: Mateusz Urbański <mateuszurbanski@yahoo.pl>
Date:   Wed Apr 21 18:46:43 2021 +0200

    Todo model

commit 98cab0239ace028ff1421345a96525403276615c
Author: Mateusz Urbański <mateuszurbanski@yahoo.pl>
Date:   Wed Apr 21 14:10:14 2021 +0200

    User model

commit 599de32cf46cbec9ae0d1dd52c4f046e49428e42
Author: Mateusz Urbański <mateuszurbanski@yahoo.pl>
Date:   Wed Apr 21 11:41:37 2021 +0200

    Setup Test Framework
```

I want to get all my changes from my latest commit `72d7e34f41b0b53992fb5d36276714d1aac4dc46` and add those to the commit from the past: `599de32cf46cbec9ae0d1dd52c4f046e49428e42`.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean :

"I want to get rid of the two intermediate commits 'User model' and 'Todo model'",
use `git rebase -i` (`-i` stands for "interactive") :

```
# specify the *parent* of the first commit :
$ git rebase -i 599de32cf^

# an editor will open, with instuctions on how to modify your history
# - delete the two commits you want to discard from these instructions
# save & exit
```

`git rebase` will then apply the script you just saved, and discard those two commits.

If you mean :

"I want to apply that 'Add missing text' modification to 'Setup Test Framework', and keep the two other commits on top of it",
again, use `git rebase -i` :

```
$ git rebase -i 599de32cf^

# in the editor that opens :
# - cut the line 'Add missing text' and paste it right after the 'Setup Test Framework' line
# - change the verb (the first word on the line) for 'Add missing text' to 'fixup'
# save & exit
```